# Actions not working on View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I have a root view open up on a view controller, however once there I am unable to push to new View Controllers. The actions were working whenever I would navigate to this page, but no longer do once I made it my root view. Here is the action I have, which is called but fails at pushing to the new view.

```
  -(IBAction)pushToSettings:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Problem");
    SettingsView *viewController = [[SettingsView alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
}
```

Is there anything wrong which is causing this action not to push to the new view?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not in a navigation interface (i.e. this view controller is now not the child of a UINavigationController). There is thus no `navigationController`, so it is `nil` and nothing happens when you send the `pushViewController` message to it.